# Python prettytable custom columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, prettytable

I'm trying to create a prettytable with 4 columns. The information I'm trying to insert per row are located in different python dictionary. I would assume the code below will work but i'm receiving the error below

```
Exception: Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) 2!=4 (expected)
```

My code is:

```
t = PrettyTable(['key', 'Start', 'End', 'Retention'])

for key, val in total.items():
    t.add_row([key, val])

for key, val in dic.items():
    t.add_row([key, val])

print(t)
```

Comment: your table is expecting 4 values for each row whereas you are entering only two values , that's the reason you are getting error

Comment: @arjunsv3691 ... yes, but I have another function that is meant to add two inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use values from both the `total` and `dic` dictionaries, You can use `zip` to iterate over them pairwise:

```
table = PrettyTable(['key', 'Start', 'End', 'Retention'])

for col_1_2, col_3_4 in zip(total.items(), dic.items()):
    table.add_row([*col_1_2, *col_3_4])
```

Comment: Part of the code worked. For dic dictionary I just want to use the values. How would i go about adding that?

Comment: @iNeed2LearnToEat Are the values of `dic` a list or a single element?

Comment: no, I just want to choose a the values from it. The code you gave me prints out both key and value

Answer (score 0):

your table is expecting 4 values for each row whereas you are entering only two values, that's the reason you are getting the error, so try this

```
 for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(total.items(), dic.items()):
        t.add_row([k, v, k2, v2])
```